# Github page not showing the contents of my index.html

Tags: github, github-pages

My code works fine locally. However, when I tried it on a GitHub page url, the content don't show only the background colors show. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**UPDATE:**

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://vanessachu.github.io/WebResume-3.0/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'. This request has been blocked; 
>   the content must be served over HTTPS.

This is error from chrome's web console, you can filter the console in DevTool to only show errors and then you will find it appears as the first error, since most of your vendors libs depends on $/jquery, you can either:

a) Download a minified jquery and place it in your `js` folder

b) Request it from a CDN that serves static assets using `https` instead of `http`. Personally prefer [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com/#/about) - https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js

Some web security readings you might find useful: [what is mixed content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content).

Comment: that's what i did

Comment: I mean I can access your link now, look s great ;)

Comment: From my side I dont see it. It doesn't display content only background

Comment: Just tried on firefox too. Not working. Could it be security issues with the code?

Comment: I can shot you the screenshot to confirm if I can figure out how to

Answer (score 0):

From the [GitHub Pages doc](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#enabling-github-pages-to-publish-your-site-from-master-or-gh-pages):

You should follow bellow steps:

```
1. On GitHub, navigate to your GitHub Pages site's repository.

2. Repository settings buttonUnder your repository name, click  Settings.

3. select-gh-pages-or-master-as-sourceUse the Select source drop-down menu to select master or gh-pages as your GitHub Pages publishing source.

4. click-save-next-to-source-selectionClick Save.
```

Comment: that's what I did

Comment: that's what i did